# Android: Show picture in ImageView nowadays

Tags: android, image, camera, imageview

So, it´s quite simple to show an Image in an ImageView in Android. I picked a Picture from the gallery, saved it´s link to my database and later I try to show it in an ImageView.

I also tried this with small images not taken by the camera, that worked. But every time I pick an image taken with the mobile phones camera, there is an error:

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (1944x2592, max 2048x2048)
```

So how can I display an image in my ImageView in days of >3 Megapixel cameras?

Answer (score 0):

your bitmap images seems to large so that there is a problem loading it. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to know about loading bitmap efficiently.